# Creating list from queries (Shopping cart like)

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html, cgi

I need your help to get to the right direction on tackling this problem. I have a list of products from different vendors stored in the database. I wanted to be able to search through it and be able to add specific products and create a "Parts Order List". I was thinking of it like a shopping cart. The user should be able to browse/search through the product list and add certain products to the "cart" and then later view and print it. I'm stuck on what language to use. I'm familiar with PHP but from reading online this is mostly possible using CGI. What do you guys think? Any other Ideas? (Hope I make sense.)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with PHP why not use PHP then?  Is there some reason you want to abandon what you know already to try something else?

**EDIT**
This beginner php tutorial on how to build a cart will teach you all you need to know about creating a similar system for your needs using sessions: http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/building-a-simple-php-shopping-cart

Comment: The thing is I don't exactly know how to implement this in PHP. The most I'm unsure about is how to create the "cart" to store the products while users can keep browsing and keep adding more items. My PHP knowledge is not that great either. I mostly use is to insert/search/update records in the database that's about it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with CGI myself, but implementing a "Cart" system that tracks a few items that a user is adding to it would be relatively simple in PHP using the global $_SESSION variable.

Comment: I've never used SESSION before, so this would be the best time to learn it. Thanks for the link justinl, atleast I have something to look at to get started. Thanks guys!

Comment: Good to hear.  It may sound a bit daunting but they're fairly straight forward to use and once you have SESSIONS in your tool belt then you'll find that opens up a lot of other doors to what you can create!